# MDX, how to pass variables/parameters? SSAS?

Tags: variables, parameters, ssas, mdx

well this is my code
but how do i replace the @anioct and @cedis for parameters for SSRS?
@anioact=is a intenger year and @cedis could be one number of a lot of number 
am i doing something bad? it work i replace @parameter for real number it does work.

```
with
member Enero as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[1],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[1],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Febrero as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[2],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[2],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
)

member Marzo as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[3],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[3],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Abril as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[4],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[4],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Mayo as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[5],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[5],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
)

member Junio as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[6],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[6],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
)

member Julio as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[7],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[7],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Agosto as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[8],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[8],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Septiembre as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[9],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[9],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Octubre as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[10],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[10],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])

)

member Noviembre as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[11],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[11],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
)

member Diciembre as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)].&[12],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[(@anioact)-1].&[12],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])


)

select {Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septiembre,Octubre,Noviembre,Diciembre} on columns,
FILTER(
{[Dimrutas].[Ruta].Members},
(([Measures].[Venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt]) > 0
)ON ROWS

from CuboBebidas
where ([Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt],[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[(@cedis)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should really use the designer to do this, but try:

```
STRTOSET(@anioact, CONSTRAINED)
```